# Change version information in a built binary

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++-6

How does one go about changing the version information in a built binary?

Specifically I have a .exe which is built with VS6 but doesn't seem to include up any of the company information or version information strings.  I'm not really even sure how they get in there in the first place, actually.  Is there a command line tool for updating this information?  How do you embed it from a command line build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 6 allows you to open a binary as Resource (it's in a drop down option in the open file dialog from memory).
You can then edit the contents of the version info resources section and then save the binary.

This always felt really dodgy to me, but one place I worked it was part of the build procedure.

If you want to get that info into the binary before you build, look at the file info resources section in the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: And, in general, it is much better to do it during the build than retroactively!

Comment: Totally agree, as I said it always felt like a broken process to edit it afterwards. From memory it was to allow the third digit of the version number (Build in .net parlance) to be set for binaries built in VB6.